# Update global variable from another module in javascript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

How do I achieve it?

I have a module named "tooltip" which has a "fade" function which in turn uses a global "element" variable. That variable is a reference to an element of the DOM. I want to update it from another module named "lightbox" so I could just let the "fade" function handle the fade-in effect. All my modules are declared using a closure.

```
    var tooltip = function{
       var element;
       return{
          fade: function(){ fade code goes here...}
       };
    }();
```

Can I just do the following to update "element" from the lightbox module?

```
tooltip.element = document.getElementByID('lightbox-con');
```

No jQuery code pls...

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. You cannot leave out the `()` in a function expression. Please correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with *module* you mean *object* then you can just do like this:

```
var tooltip = {
    element: null,
    fade: function() {
        //fade code goes here...
        // you can access the element via this.element
    }
}
```

**then** you can update the element as you described:

```
tooltip.element = document.getElementByID('lightbox-con');
```

---

But if `element` is only used in the `fade` function, you could also consider to just pass the element to that function:

```
var tooltip = {
    fade: function(element) {
       //fade code goes here...
    }
}
```

and do:

```
tooltip.fade(document.getElementByID('lightbox-con'));
```

It depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: I guess that's basically it. tooltip and lightbox are objects, each in a separate file. Just started learning so I am still finding my way around..

Comment: @Joann: Not sure if I understand. In your original code, `element` is not a global variable. It is local to the anonymous function. You cannot change it the way you described with your original code.